# Is this quantity divisible by $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $$x_{1} = \binom{2p-1}{p}-1$$ $$x_{2}=\binom{3p-1}{2p}-\binom{2p-1}{p}$$ $$x_{3} = \binom{4p-1}{3p}-\binom{3p-1}{2p}$$ and I observed that for small values of $p$ $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ is divisible by $p$. Is it true in general that $x_{k}\equiv0\pmod{p}$ for all $k$?

Comment: $x_1$ always is. Which values did you check? $x_2$ is always $-1$ mod $p$ (eg for $p=3$, $x_2=\left(6\atop4\right)-1=14$).

Comment: After you figure out what you really wanted to conjecture (see stewbasic's counterexample to the current formulation), please take a look at [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem). Most likely it will settle the question.

Comment: By the symmetry of Pascal's triangle, every positive integer $k$ satisfies $\dbinom{kp-1}{\left(k-1\right)p} = \dbinom{kp-1}{p-1}$. So you need to show that the remainder of $\dbinom{kp-1}{p-1}$ modulo $p$ does not depend on $k$. See Proposition 5.5 in http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/fleck.pdf for this.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Nice results in those files (the elementary one's).  Pheww some are so so messsy ;)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks Darij. That was helpful. It never struck me.

Comment: The link I gave above needs to be replaced by http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/fleck.pdf .